# Make data model for locations for shipping

Tags: database, google-maps, gps, datamodel

I am making this web app which uses a concept like ebay.. pick up stuff from local stores and deliver. The problem is they have delivery circles, and deliver to specific areas. So I was stuck on how to model the data. This is what I was getting to, but it just doesn't seem right.

```
AreaCodes(**areaID**, areaName, PincodeList<>)
Delivers(vendorID, AreaID)
```

Is there a better and more detailed way of doing this. because I think its really a very vague way to make boundaries using pin codes, because the vendors are generally local shops who might have there own way of making there delivery radius.

Any help would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

```
DeliveryCircle (id, schedule, ...)
DeliveryArea (id, name, ......)
AreaPinCode(id, deliveryAreaId name, ...)
Delivery (devliveryCircleId, itemDetails, vendorId, areaPinCodeId, ...)
```

Targeting deliveries to pincode might do the trick.